# Cannot Segue Away From Row Action Button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I have a table view that is listing a bunch of children.  When the user swipes on the row, three actions appear `Arrived`, `Departed`, `Attendance`.  `Arrived` and `Departed` work fine, no issues.  When the user taps on `Attendance`, I want to segue away from the table view and pass the data from that `indexPath` for use in another table view (to display children's attendance history).

#### Here is the code for the `attendance` action

```
    let attendance = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Attendance", handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
        tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("childrenToAttendance", sender: self)
```

#### Here is the code for the segue away from the action that passes the data (childID)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "childrenToChild" {
        let singleChildViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SingleChildViewController

        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell) {
            singleChildViewController.childID = childID[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
    if segue.identifier == "childrenToAttendance" {
        let attendanceViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ChildAttendanceTableViewController

        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell) {
            attendanceViewController.passedChildID = childID[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

The first segue, `childrenToChild` works fine, no issues.  The second segue, `childrenToAttendance` is where the issue is.  The app builds and runs fine, but when I tap on `Attendance`, I get the following error.

`Could not cast value of type '<<app name>>.ChildrenTableViewController' (0x1074a8400) to 'UITableViewCell' (0x109ea9128).`

Error is on line `if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell)`

The segue is wired from the origin `tableview` to the destination `tableview`, it can't go from origin `tableviewcell` since that is already being used.  I tried to wire it from the cell but that deleted my other segue (can't have two segue's navigating away from one cell).

I've also tried switching the `sender` in the `performSegueWithIdentifier` line, such as `nil`, `AnyObject` but no success.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, your problem is that in this line,

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("childrenToAttendance", sender: self)
```

you are passing `self`, which is a view controller and not a `UITableViewCell` that you are trying to force-unwrap.

Probably the simplest thing to do here is to pass the table view cell instead:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("childrenToAttendance", sender: cell)
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks so much!  Marked as answer.